# BGP multi-path using loopback

Tags: cisco, routing, bgp, cisco-nexus

[image]

I have above scenario where i have multiple PATH for my BGP so i have to setup loopback interface to make it `ECMP` routing on both path.

I have cisco nexus switches and following is my `first` router config:

```
router bgp 65001
  log-neighbor-changes
  address-family ipv4 unicast
    network 200.200.200.0/24
  neighbor 10.0.0.1
    remote-as 65002
```

Question:

- do i need to add `update-source loopback0` in bgp config and why?
- do i need `ebgp-multihop 2` ( I doubt because it use for two different path to different devices)

let me know anything i missing here?

**EDIT:**

loopback doesn't support `access-list` in that case do i need to add access list on my two physical interface?

Router running `eBGP` ( sorry i forgot to mention )

Comment: Your diagram is confusing because it only lists a single AS, so that would be iBGP. It is eBGP if it is between two different ASes.

Comment: Your configuration shows iBGP.  Please edit the listing and/or diagram to reflect that.

Comment: It was typo, anyway I have fixed AS number now it’s different AS. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I need to add `update-source loopback0` in BGPconfig and why?

Yes, otherwise the router will use the closest interface, which would be either f0/0 or f0/1.  The BGP process is expecting the BGP packet's source address to be the one listed in the neighbor statement, so the peering will never form.  You ***also*** need to have IGP routing so that your loopbacks are reachable from each other.

> Do I need `ebgp-multihop` 2?

No.  Since you are using iBGP, not eBGP, there is no need for the `ebgp-multihop` statement.

Note: You might consider configuring the two links as a single Etherchannel, which may make things easier to understand/troubleshoot.

**EDIT**

If you're trying to secure your BGP peers, an easier way might be to configure BGP keys on the peer.  They act like passwords, authenticating the BGP session.

Comment: I think the layer-3 etherchannel is a very good idea. It can simplify things, and it will fail over the fastest.

Comment: Thanks, i have edit my question - loopback doesn't support access-list in that case do i need to add access list on my two physical interface?

Comment: instead of `IGP` i can use `static` route also right?

Comment: Yes.  But if you configure an Etherchannel, you don't need to use loopbacks.

Comment: because of some complexity we decided this path, in diagram they are looking direct link but in real world they are going via two distinct L2 switches. I love LACP but we have limitation here :(

Comment: Could you answer my edit question about `loopback` interface `access-list`, is it ok to apply access-list on two physical interface or there is an other way?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have access-list to restrict some traffic from remote end and want to implement ACL on `inbound` interface, and as you know `loopback` doesn't support `ip access-group FOO in` command so question is should i need to add that command on 2 physical interface connected to remote end?

Comment: Yes, put them on the physical interfaces.  Also, you can apply ACLs on the VTY and SNMP.

Comment: I am getting this error in debug - `Single hop EBGP peer xx.xx.xx.xx not directly attached (active), outbound interface Unknown`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94560/discussion-between-ron-trunk-and-satish).

Comment: as soon as i add `ebgp-multihop 2` my BGP is up and working.. hmm

Comment: Meet me on chat

Comment: Then you're running eBGP.  Please edit your question to reflect that.

Answer (score -1):

maximum-paths eibgp x

replace the number with X ( your total paths )

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. You could improve your answer by editing it to add more details to make it more useful both for the original poster and future users. Typically short answers like this could provide reasoning why you believe this is the answer, more explanation about the concepts mentioned, references/links to supporting resources, or applicable examples.